# How to find the tallest patient in each ward

Tags: sql

I have two tables:

`patient (patient_id (PK), patient_name, gender, height, weight, staff_no, ward_no)`

`ward (ward_no (PK), ward_name, number_of_beds)`

I want to find the tallest patient in each ward.

This is my query:

```
Select patient_name, MAX(height) from patient Group By patient_name
```

Does this query work?

**This is a mock exam question so I have the model answer.**

```
select patient_name 
from patient p1 
where not exists (select * from patient p2 where p1.ward_no = p2.ward_no and p1.height < p2 .height)
```

I don't understand the sub-query can some one explain it please.
Thank you

Comment: Ok so about Your `model answer`, your sub-query uses the`NOT EXISTS` condition, this condition returns true when the subquery doesn't return anything. 
In Your case when You have for example patients with `ward_no=1` so it will iter over every patient in this ward and for every will execute the subquery asking db like like this "give me all patients from this same ward which height is bigger than current patient i am iterating over".So when there will be no higher patient subquery will be empty and `not exists` will be true, current patient is truly the highest coz there is no higher patient.

Answer (score 2):

Strange answer.  I would go with the more direct:

```
select p.patient_name 
from patient p
where p.height = (select max(p2.height)
                  from patient p2
                  where p2.ward_no = p.ward_no 
                 ) ;
```

The correlated subquery is getting the maximum height for all patients in the ward of a given patient.  It then returns all patients who match this height.

Your version is doing something similar.  It is saying "there is no patient in the ward with a larger height".  Sometimes, this is expressed using `all` on exams:

```
select p.patient_name 
from patient p
where p.height >= all (select p2.height
                       from patient p2
                       where p2.ward_no = p.ward_no 
                      ) ;
```

In practice, `any` and `all` are used less frequently.

Comment: would something like this works 
Select patient_name,MAX(height) form patient Group By ward_no 
works ? and i don't get it what this part will return p1.height < p2 .height ?

Comment: @mango90001: No. You group by `ward_no`. Per `ward_no` exist many patients. You select one `patient_name`, but you don't tell the DBMS which.

Comment: @mango90001: p1 is the row you are looking at in the `WHERE` clause in order to decide whether to have it in your results or not. p2 is the person you are comparing it with. The `WHERE` clause asks: Is there a p2 in the same ward as p1 that has a greater height?

Comment: Maybe i didn't understand it right p1.height < p2 .height will return false p1.height will always be equal to p2.height right ? I'm talking about the model answer.

Comment: No `p1.height < p2 .height`  won't be always equal. The `p2` is alias for this same table (it is expression not instance) it acts like this "take some patient from p1 , now find in this same table another patient with same ward_no and there some patients with higher height"..

Answer (score 0):

This is your query:

```
Select patient_name, MAX(height) from patient Group By patient_name;
```

You want to find the tallest person in each ward, but the ward does not even appear anywhere in your query ;) It would rather be the ward you'd be grouping by, so as to get one result row per ward and show the tallest person in that row.

However, you'd need an aggregation function that would give you the patient for the maximum height. The only DBMS I know of supporting such function is Oracle (`KEEP FIRST/LAST`). This shows us that with SQL questions you should always tell us which DBMS you are asking for.

Oracle's function would return one person per ward. But what if there are two tallest persons with the same height in a ward? With such top n questions (the five nicest, the two lowest, the one tallest per ...) you should always state what to do in case of ties.

As to the model answer: Yes, this is one way to solve this. Find persons for which no other person exist in the same ward with a greater height. You use the person table twice, with different aliases so you have one alias for the person you want to check and another for the person(s) you are comparing it with. There are several other ways to solve the same problem.